# What is the impact of Daylight Saving Time on BIND9?

Tags: bind

There is no parameter in bind9 to set daylight saving time, how to know if daylight saving time affects BIND9's behavior

Comment: You would need to explain why you think there is a relationship and what you want to do. Also this is not a programming related question; hence offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

Daylight savings time shouldn't effect BIND. After all not much of DNS depends on absolute time.